# Tail recursion cons operator Scala

Tags: scala, tail

If the last statement in a function is func(x,tailList):

```
    def func(x:Int):List[Int]...
    case head :: tailList => head :: func(x,tailList)
```

converting this function to tail recursion requires accumulator to be added as a third parameter (and to keep it clean adding a local function inside func() ).

```
    insertTail(x,tailList,head::acc)
```

doesn't seem to work correctly. shouldn't "acc" hold the computation in progress?

Am I missing something here to make it tail recursive work with accumulator?

Adding a more complete example

```
def funcTailTest(x:Int,xs:List[Int]):List[Int] =  {
@tailrec
def inner(x:Int,xs:List[Int],acc:List[Int]) : List[Int] = xs match {

  case head::tailList => {
    inner(x,tailList,head::acc)
  }
}
inner(x,xs,Nil)

}
```

basically head should be added to the output of inner() function so w/o an attempt to make it tail recursive last statement in a case will look

```
head::inner(x,tailList)
```

Comment: It would help, if you'd provide a somewhat more complete example.

Comment: What should happen with ``x``? Should it be added to the end of ``tailList``?

Comment: Edited question with adding a complete example.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to make your function do, but you  need a pattern match for the case where `xs` is empty, which just outputs `acc`. I usually add a default parameter for the empty list (i.e. `acc: List[Int] = Nil`, which means you don't need the inner loop at all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that reverse is also tail recursively implemented (which it definitely can be), the following is a tail recursive append:

```
def append[T](y: T, xs: List[T]): List[T] = {
  @tailrec
  def appendAcc[T](y: T, xs: List[T], acc: List[T]): List[T] = xs match {
    case Nil => y :: acc
    case x :: xs => appendAcc(y, xs, x :: acc)
  }

  appendAcc(y, xs, Nil).reverse
}
```

Comment: Reverse is not tail recursive. It is not recursive at all. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1 But you are right it is very simple to write it in a tail recursive way.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a scala function to implement Tail recursion using cons operator

```
def reverseUtility(ele: List[Int], res: List[Int]):List[Int] ={
  ele match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: Nil => x :: res
  case x :: y => reverseUtility(y, (x::res))
}}
```

Pass a list of `Int` and an empty list called `res(result)` as parameters for the function. Time complexity for the function is O(N)